# Nested generic trait parameter gives "unconstrained type parameter"

Tags: generics, rust

Consider the next snippet:

```rust
trait GenericTrait<T> {
    fn value(&self) -> T;
}

struct GenericStruct<U> {
    field: U,
}

impl<T: PartialEq, U: GenericTrait<T>> PartialEq for GenericStruct<U> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        <U as GenericTrait<T>>::value(&self.field) == <U as GenericTrait<T>>::value(&other.field)
    }
}
```

it gives me

```bash
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/lib.rs:34:6
   |
34 | impl<T: PartialEq, U: GenericTrait<T>> PartialEq for GenericStruct<U> {
   |      ^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
```

Ok, if I add this trait to `GenericStruct` definition

```rust
struct GenericStruct<T, U: GenericTrait<T>> {
    field: U,
}
```

I'm getting

```bash
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
  --> src/lib.rs:30:22
   |
30 | struct GenericStruct<T, U: GenericTrait<T>> {
   |                      ^ unused parameter
   |
   = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
   = help: if you intended `T` to be a const parameter, use `const T: usize` instead

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0392`.
```

So, am I forced to add a "dummy" field to a `GenericStruct` like

```rust
struct GenericStruct<T, U: GenericTrait<T>> {
    field: U,
    _dummy: PhantomData<*const T>,
}
```

to make it work or is there some better approach to this problem?

Comment: Because `GenericTrait` is *parameterised* by `T` (rather than it being an associated type), `GenericStruct<U>` could have multiple implementations of `GenericTrait` each with a different substitution for type parameter `T`.  How is the compiler to know *which* such `T` you wish to use in the implementation of `PartialEq`?  That it's obvious to you suggests to me that `T` probably should be an associated type of `GenericTrait` and not a type parameter.

Comment: Otherwise, if it's a property of `GenericStruct<U>` then a `PhantomData<T>` field is probably the best way.  (Alternatively you could use a type projection through another, non-generic trait—which might be more appropriate if you wish to keep such associated type decoupled from the type itself).

Comment: Note that putting a pointer in `PhantomData` is not a good idea: it will make the struct `!Send + !Sync`. Use `PhantomData<fn() -> T>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: all of these are covariant over `T` so why not just `PhantomData<T>`?

Comment: @eggyal Because it makes `Send` and `Sync` depend on `T`. And similarly for other auto traits.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: as does `PhantomData<T>` per its implementations of [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#impl-Send) and [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#impl-Sync) though?

Comment: @eggyal `PhantomData<T>` makes the containing struct `Send` etc. only if `T` is. `PhantomData<fn() -> T>` is always `Send+Sync+Unpin` etc..

Comment: Ah, misunderstood what you were saying.  Yeah, I see that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an associated type instead of generics:

```rust
trait GenericTrait {
    type Output;
    fn value(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

struct GenericStruct<U> {
    field: U,
}

impl<T: PartialEq, U: GenericTrait<Output=T>> PartialEq for GenericStruct<U> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        <U as GenericTrait>::value(&self.field) == <U as GenericTrait>::value(&other.field)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d07aadc366894f44880c4bea7a53ed5)